# Bootstrap is just working on Safari

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I don't understand, It looks like bootstrap isn't loading on Chrome or IE, but on Safari it Works just fine.

Anyone Please? I really don't know what is going on here.

[Here is the Website](http://www.intrinsecusmovie.com/index.html)

And here is the Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

<title>Bootstrap Intrinsecus</title>
<!-- Bootstrap link folder-->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/csc" rel="stylesheet"/> 

<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>

<!--Black-Head-->  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Style_1.css" />  
<!--link to my .css file---->
<div class="well row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> 
    <div class="navbar-header" > - INTRINSECUS - 
    </div> </nav>
</div>
<!--------- Script from Google Analytics--------------->
```

```
<!------- End of Black HEAD------------------->

 <!-------starting buttons------------------>
<div class=" well well-sm">
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3"> 
              <button class="btn">
                  <a href="index.html">
                      <h6 class="font"> HOME </h6>
                </a>
       </button>
</div>
              <div class="col-xs-3"> 
              <button class="btn">
                  <a href="story.html">
                      <h6 class="font"> STORY </h6>
                </a>
       </button>
</div>    
      <div class="col-xs-3"> 
              <button class="btn">
                  <a href="galery.html">
                      <h6 class="font"> PHOTOS </h6>
                </a>
       </button>
</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3"> 
              <button class="btn">
                  <a href="credits.html">
                      <h6 class="font"> CREDITS </h6>
                </a>
       </button>
</div>
          </div>  <!-- end of row "560" height="315"-->
      </div>      <!-- end of well -->
```

> body

```
<body>
     <div class="row video-container"> 
     <iframe  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/FZB8kOtBJf4?autoplay=1;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen > </iframe>
      </div>

<!-----Social Buttons-------------->
<div class="well row">
<div class=" col-md-12 col-xs-12 ">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 social">            
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/intrinsecusmovie/?ref=bookmarks" target="_blank"> 
         <span class="pull-right"> <h2> <i class="fa fa-facebook-square social"> 
            </i>
            </h2>
         </span>
        </a>

         <span class="pull-right space"> <h5>Follow us</h5> </span>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet"></script>
     </body>
      <footer>
        <div class="container-fluid">
      <span class="pull-left">&copy; 2017 Intrinsecus
      </span>
           </div>
         </footer>
          </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including two bootstrap file on your site, remove one:
[image]

Bootstrap requires jquery 1.9.0 or higher to work fine try with this and remove the 1.X.X you have loaded:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've just seen you link a missed bootstrap.css file also:

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/csc" rel="stylesheet">
```

but in the css folder there's just your style sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help @vlk but nothing changed :/

Comment: I'm looking at your website with inspector, I've not seen the change on code. Please upload changes so I'll check the console.

Comment: And now I've just update my answer because I've seen you're linking a missed bootstrap.js file.

Comment: Thank you very very much. you definitely solved the problem. It's done, working amazing now.

Comment: I didn't tested on IE yet but I think it's going to work as it's working on Chrome now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have placed an incorrect type for the bootstrap link
this

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/csc" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

should be (type=text/css)

```
  <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @repzero. I really appreciated.